# How can I implement page objects with Selenium and node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, pageobjects

I'm really struggling with the async nature of node and Selenium. I've created a page object class to encapsulate a login page but I don't know how to make a client wait for a response from my page object class. For example, I have a page object method called isUserLoggedIn() which should return true or false depending on some elements on the page. The problem I'm having is everything Selenium returns is a promise so I can't really wait for a result. On the client end, I don't want to receive a promise because I'd have to write some logic to deal with whatever promise I get back. Ideally my isUserLoggedIn() method would simply return a true or false but I can't even make that happen because of the async nature of the Selenium API. How can I use page objects in Selenium javascript?

Comment: You should leave the resolution of the Promise to the testing library (jasmine, mocha or whatever). Adding some logic in a test is a bad practice.

Comment: @FlorentB. don't I need some logic to control a page (waiting for certain amt of time, clicking sequences of buttons etc)?

Comment: selenium has some waiters to synchronize the steps. Waiting a certain amount of time is also a bad practice since the time to build the DOM or get a response from an Ajax request is non-deterministic.